# Is $f(\operatorname{rad}A)\subseteq\operatorname{rad}B$ for $f\colon A\to B$ not necessarily surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

If I have two $K$-algebras $A$ and $B$ (associative, with identity) and an algebra homomorphism $f\colon A\to B$, is it true that $f(\operatorname{rad}A)\subseteq\operatorname{rad}B$, where $\operatorname{rad}$ denotes the Jacobsen radical, the intersection of all maximal right ideals?

I can think of two proofs in the case that $f$ is surjective, but both depend on this surjectivity in a crucial way. The first uses the formulation of $\operatorname{rad}A$ as the set of $a\in A$ such that $1-ab$ is invertible for all $b\in A$, and the second treats an algebra as a module over itself, and uses the fact that the radical of $A$ as a module agrees with the radical of $A$ as an algebra, and is the intersection of kernels of maps onto simple modules; here the surjectivity is needed to make $B$ into an $A$-module in such a way that the radical of $B$ as an $A$-module is contained in the radical of $B$ as a $B$-module.

If a counter example exists, $A$ will have to be infinite-dimensional, as in the finite dimensional case all elements of $\operatorname{rad}A$ are nilpotent, and (I think, although I don't remember a proof right now, so maybe I'm wrong) that the radical always contains every nilpotent element.

This is my first question on here, so let me know if I should have done anything differently!

Comment: Dear Matt, welcome to this site. Your question is extremely clear and shows you have thought about it carefully.The prediction that a counterexample will be infinite dimensional has an absolutely correct proof . So, no: definitely don't do anything differently!

Comment: That the radical contains all nilpotents follows from the pleasantly analogous characterization (in the commutative case) of the set of nilpotents as the intersection of all *prime* ideals, which is obviously smaller than the Jacobson radical, where you intersect only the *maximal* ideals.

Comment: Typesetting exercise: \operatorname{rad} versus \mathrm{rad}: $\operatorname{rad} A$ versus $\mathrm{rad} A$.  A difference should be visible.

Comment: @Georges: alternately, note that by Schur's lemma any element of a ring that acts nontrivially on a simple module acts invertibly, but a nilpotent element can never act invertibly.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks for that, I thought the spacing was off.

Comment: Thanks for your proof , Qiaochu.

Comment: "the radical always contains every nilpotent element": That's not true (unless I'm missing a commutativity assumption in the question). For instance $\mathbb{M}_n(K)$ where $n>1$ contains many nonzero nilpotent elements but has zero radical.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is false that the Jacobson radical is sent to the Jacobson radical.

Take $A=K[X]_{(X)}$ [localization at  $(X)$],  $B=K(X)$ and the inclusion $f:K[X]_{(X)}\hookrightarrow K(X)$
Then $f(Rad(A))=f(XK[X]_{(X)})=XK[X]_{(X)} \nsubseteq Rad(B)=Rad(K(X))=(0)$

Comment: I like this example Georges. It also serves to show that for a dominant map of irreducible $K$-schemes $X\rightarrow Y$, without finiteness hypotheses, $\dim(X)$ need not be greater than or equal to $\dim(Y)$. I think I will always remember $K[X]_{(X)}$ now!

Comment: Ah, but I hadn't thought of this interesting consequence/interpretation: thanks a lot, @Keenan!

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty obviously wrong: Take $A$  to be the ring of upper-triangular $2 \times 2 $-matrices  $ \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {K } & {K}  \\
   {0 } & {K }  \\
\end{array}} \right]$, $B$  to be the ring of all $2\times 2$ -matrices $ \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {K } & {K}  \\
   {K } & {K }  \\
\end{array}} \right]$, and $f$  to be the canonical inclusion. Then $radA=\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {0 } & {K}  \\
   {0 } & {0 }  \\
\end{array}} \right]$ and $radB=0$. However, when $f$ is a surjective homomorphism of $K$-algebras, it is right. In this case, the inclusion $f(radA)\subseteq radB$ is clear since, for any maximal
left ideal $m$ of $B$, the inverse image $f^{-1}(m)$ is a maximal left ideal of $A$.

Comment: To give an example of strict inclusion, let $A=Z$ and let
$f$ be the natural projection of $A$ onto $B=Z/4Z$. Here, $f(radA)=f(0)=0$ but $ radB=2Z/4Z\neq0$