# Is $f(\operatorname{rad} A ) \subseteq \operatorname{rad} B$ when $f$ is a not surjective $K$-algebras homomorphism and $K$ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, representation-of-algebras

Let $K$ be a field. For a $K$-algebra $A$ take the definition of the Jacobson radical of $A$ as the intersection of all maximal left ideals of $A$. If $A$ and $B$ are two finite dimensional $K$-algebras is it true that any homomorphism **not necessarily surjective** $f$ sends the Jacobson radical of $A$ to the Jacobson radical of $B$, that is, $f(\operatorname{rad} A)\subseteq \operatorname{rad} B$ ?

[image]

Both $A$ and $B$ are **not commutative** $K$-algebras.

In one hand, I was wondering if it is possible to understand this result as a particular case of the well known $C$-module version (as the radical of a $K$-algebra $C$ coincides with the radical of $C$ regarded as a right $C$-module):

*Let $C$ be a $K$-algebra. If $M$ and $N$ are two right $C$-modules, then $f(\operatorname{rad} M)\subseteq \operatorname{rad} N$ for any right $C$-module homomorphism $f$.*

Take $M=A\ $ and $N=B\ $ be two modules over the $K$-algebra $C=K$, then by using the preceding result we have $f(\operatorname{rad} A)\subseteq \operatorname{rad} B$.

The reason I am asking here is that, in the other hand we can find a counter example using 2x2 matrices here:

[Is $f(\operatorname{rad}A)\subseteq\operatorname{rad}B$ for $f\colon A\to B$ not necessarily surjective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110318/is-f-operatornamerada-subseteq-operatornameradb-for-f-colon-a-to-b-not/227507#227507)

If $f$ is surjective, then the result is ok. What to do if $f$ is not surjective ?

So, any hint on what detail I am missing here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: I am confused. The question you linked has already a counterexample right?

Comment: Exactly, the question I linked has already a counterexample, but what I don't understand is how this is not a contradiction with the fact that $f(\operatorname{rad} M)\subseteq \operatorname{rad} N$ is true for any homomorphism of right $A$-modules $f:M\rightarrow N$. Let $M=A$ and $N=B$ be two modules over the $K$-algebra $K$, then we have $f(\operatorname{rad} A)\subseteq \operatorname{rad} B$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  Thank you! I will try to compute rad B as an A-module.

Comment: Now I am confused as well :-), maybe someone can clear this up? For a (left) $A$-module $M$, let us write $\mathrm{rad}_A(M)$ for the intersection of all maximal $A$-submodules of $M$. For $A$ itself, let us "abbreviate" $\mathrm{rad}(A) := \mathrm{rad}_A(A)$. We have the following lemma (see [SE/4464985](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464985)): If $f : M \to N$ is a homomorphism of $A$-modules, we have $f(\mathrm{rad}_A(M)) \subseteq \mathrm{rad}_A(N)$. What does it tell us about rings? [...]

Comment: [...] If $f : A \to B$ is a ring homomorphism, we can use $f$ to make $B$ an $A$-module ($a \odot b := f(a) \cdot b$), and then $f$ is also an $A$-module homomorphism. So the Lemma implies $f(\mathrm{rad}_A(A)) \subseteq \mathrm{rad}_A(B)$. Notice that the right hand side is *not* $\mathrm{rad}_B(B)$, but since every $B$-submodule of $B$ (= left ideal of $B$) is also an $A$-submodule of $B$, we clearly have $\mathrm{rad}_A(B) \subseteq \mathrm{rad}_B(B)$, so eventually $f(\mathrm{rad}(A)) \subseteq \mathrm{rad}(B)$. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me transform the comments into an answer.

The [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110318) already provides a counterexample, and the question is only about why this is not a contradiction to the (correct) statement about modules.

For a (left) $A$-module $M$, let us write $\mathrm{rad}_A(M)$ for the intersection of all maximal $A$-submodules of $M$. For $A$ itself, we usually "abbreviate" $\mathrm{rad}(A):=\mathrm{rad}_A(A)$. (Actually, this abbreviation is the source of confusion here.)

We have the following lemma (see [SE/4464985](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464985)):

> If $f : M \to N$ is a homomorphism of $A$-modules, we have $f(\mathrm{rad}_A(M)) \subseteq \mathrm{rad}_A(N)$.

What does it tell us about rings?

If $f:A \to B$ is a ring homomorphism, we can use $f$ to make $B$ an $A$-module $(a \odot b := f(a) \cdot b$), and then $f$ is also an $A$-module homomorphism. So the Lemma merely implies
$$f(\mathrm{rad}_A(A)) \subseteq \mathrm{rad}_A(B).$$
The point is that that the right hand side is *not* $\mathrm{rad}_B(B)$, and also we will not have $\mathrm{rad}_A(B) \subseteq \mathrm{rad}_B(B)$.

The simplest example (commutative, albeit not finite-dimensional) is $A = K[X]_{(X)}$, $B = K(X)$, $f$ is the inclusion. Here, $\mathrm{rad}_A(A)= \langle X \rangle = X \cdot K[X]_{(X)}$, $\mathrm{rad}_B(B)=0$, but $X \in \mathrm{rad}_A(B)$ so $\mathrm{rad}_A(B) \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you Martin and Mariano for the clarifications.